# In the new Blazor Web App template using .net 8, how do I make an HTTP request from a InteractiveWebAssembly mode component?

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I need to get some informatino from a web API.  On .net 7 I just injected HttpClient to the Blazor component but now it says:

> There is no registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.

In some videos I saw they talked about making the request using a CascadingParameter but I have not being able to find a working example using that approach.

I also tried defining it as an CascadingParameter.  As a cascading parameter it is just null.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution, maybe it will be usefull for someone else.

Besides adding the scoped service in program.cs in the client project, similr to this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

It must also be defined in program.cs of the server project (or main project).  The line should contain the base address of the server such as:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7178"));
```

The issue that I see is that the URL is hardcoded or can be saved in a json file, but it must be changed anytime the server URL changes.

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. I still don't understand why that works or how it works. Why do we have to register it in both projects? If you want to make it even more clear, I'd love to see that added to your existing answer. Again, thanks a lot, you saved me.

Comment: After some research and checking on Mark's alternate solution, the issue comes up that by default InteractiveWebAssembly prerenders the page on the server.  This means that the server must have the HttpClient service as well.  To avoid creating a HttpClient on the server, as Mark suggested, prerender must be disabled at the webpage.  This will add some delay for showing up the page since the user's browser now has to download the entire webassembly before displaying something.

Comment: Prerendering is actually a great feature, in my opinion. I ended up wrapping my call to the web API within the OnAfterRenderAsync method when the firstRender argument is true. This way, I can render the page server-side without data (including a loading indicator) and then have a single call to my backend and rerender the page interactively once the data is returned. Works for me right now.

Comment: That is a good approach, easier than implementing an access method por de server. I'll try it.

Comment: Also see [How to Fetch Data from Server in Blazor Interactive Auto Render Mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOF9Q8vAJ-o) for another approach.

Comment: After adding HttpClient to the Program.cs how to use it in the .razor component? Example: `var result = await HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Model>("path")`. Simply injecting `@inject HttpClient HttpClient` doesn't work. I suppose there is something to do with the registered client's name - "WebAPI".

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution is to use the following in the page instead

`@rendermode @(new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(false))`

In addition you need to add the following to Program.cs as well

`builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("WebAPI"));`

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this question didn't work for me but put me on the right path.

I got this from Microsoft's documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-8.0#client-side-services-for-httpclient-fail-during-prerendering)

You must register the service like normal in the client Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
});
```

Then you must also register the service in the server Program.cs (for prerendering)

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
```

Then you can use it this way in your .razor file.

```
@inject HttpClient Client

@code {
    var response = await Client.GetAsync("ping");
}
```